# Rails 3 - ID within parent resource (Articles, Comments) instead of overall id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, comments

I haven't found a single result related to my question when googleing, but it appears to me to be a fairly simple question:
Given is an article model and a comment model. Now, on the article show page, when listing all the article's comments, each comment should have its chronological id within that article, not its overall id.

The associations and everything work fine but I have no idea how to implement the 'relative' comment_id without going the rather complicated way and manually adding an article_comment_id column to my comment model and dealing with that attribute in my controller.

Is there no easy method to call an objects id within its parent model that it belongs_to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not an automatic way to ask a record where it is indexed with its peers.

The way I've done this is just to keep track of the index while iterating through the array.

So for ERB:

```
<% @article.comments.each_with_index do |comment, index| %>
    <div class="comment_id"><%= index + 1 %></div>
    <div class="content"><%= comment.content %></div>
```

Or HAML:

```
-@article.comments.each_with_index do |comment, index|
    .comment_id= index + 1
    .content= comment.content
```

If your paginating, you'll need to have `index + 1 + (page*num_items)` or something.

You could save an index in the database, by adding a column such as `iteration_id` and then add an before-create filter to the Comment model like this:

```
before_create do
  last_comment = article.comments.unscoped.order("iteration_id DESC").select('iteration_id').first
  self.iteration_id = last_comment ? last_comment.iteration_id + 1 : 0
  true
end
```

You'd need to do something when comments are destroyed as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: All your approaches are awesome! Thank you very much! I especially like the before_create filter! I think I'm gonna go that way with the extra attribute in the comment table. For a possible citation feature later, that iteration_id attribute should work totally fine right? (For example citing a comment by simply writing a comment's iteration_id (#15 i.e.) in the comment form(I'm planning to implement such a feature))

Comment: Yep - iteration_id would work perfectly for that. You're very welcome.

Comment: I implemented the iteration_id and everything works fine, however, there is one issue, which is a logic result: When a comment is deleted, the comments.count will be -1 so there might be comments having the same iteration_id. Now, one approach could be to completely fake the destroy action and rather create a "viewable"-attr for each comment, so that this count never will be affected. But this approach wouldn't be efficient. What would be best is a kind of count-buffer, that always keeps the last count value and never can be reduced, on which the + 1 is made. Is there something like that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You will need to add code for updating all the iteration_ids if one is deleted. You're probably best doing this in one SQL update.

Comment: That's such a lovely piece of code! Now that I see it, it seems intuitive. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through them using a partial:

```
<%= render @article.comments %>
```

Inside the partial, you can reference the count of the comments with `comment_count`. This is an automatic feature that is provided by Rails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ryan! I'm currently following the approach from iHiD but thank you anyway for that great comment_count method!